# Почему тип возвращаемого значения неверный?

Tags: java

Имеется класс `Book`:

```
class Book{
    String author;    //автор

    //конструктор
    Book(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Далее имеется класс `Library`, агрегирующий массив типа `Book`:

```
class Library{
    private String nameLibrary;
    private ArrayList<Book> libraryList = new ArrayList<>();

    void addBookToLibrary(Book c){
        libraryList.add(c);
    }

    //получить список всех авторов (!)
    String getAllAuthors(){
        for(Book b : libraryList) return b.getAuthor();
}
```

Почему при попытке получить список всех авторов в классе `Main`, выводится только один автор?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //создаем библиотеку
        Library lib = new Library("Gold Library");

        //тут создали авторов...
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Петя 1"));
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Петя 2"));
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Петя 3"));
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Петя 4"));
        lib.addBookToLibrary(new Book("Петя 5"));

        //пытаемся получить всех авторов
        System.out.println(lib.getAllAuthors());
}
```

`Вывод консоли:`

`Петя 1`

Вопрос: что не так в реализации метода `getAllAuthors`?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что тип неверный? Тип верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даю ответ скорее для наглядности...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Library lib = new Library("Gold Library")
                .addBookToLibrary("Петя 1")
                .addBookToLibrary("Петя 2")
                .addBookToLibrary("Петя 3")
                .addBookToLibrary("Петя 4")
                .addBookToLibrary("Петя 5");

        System.out.println(lib.getNameLibrary());
        System.out.println(lib.getAllAuthors());
    }

}

class Book{

    private final String author;

    public Book(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Library {

    private final String nameLibrary;
    private final List<Book> libraryList;

    public Library (String nameLibrary) {
        this.libraryList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.nameLibrary = nameLibrary;
    }

    public String getNameLibrary() {
        return nameLibrary;
    }

    public List<String> getAllAuthors() {
        return libraryList.stream().map(Book::getAuthor).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Library addBookToLibrary (String author){
        return addBookToLibrary(new Book(author));
    }

    public Library addBookToLibrary(Book book) {
        libraryList.add(book);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

После **return** ваш цикл **завершает** работу.

```
String getAllAuthors() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Book b : libraryList) {
        sb.append(b.getAuthor());
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); 
    } 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: x лучше на StringBuilder поменять

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev заменил )

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы увидеть что-то наподобие этого:

```
class Library{
     //список авторов
    List<Book> getAllAuthors(){
        List<Book> lb = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Book b : libraryList) lb.add(b);
    return lb;
    }
}


 Library lib = new Library("Gold Library");    

 List<Book> getAllAuthor = lib.getAllAuthors();
    for(Book b : getAllAuthor) System.out.println(b.getAuthor());
```